# Frontend tag edit/submit form

Tags: functions, tags, wp-insert-post

I would like to have a separate page to submit/edit tags.

Any user can edit or submit tags. But it should be published only after admin approval.

Is there any function available like `wp_insert_tag()`?

### Update:

After Kaiser's answer I've tried like this.

```
$x = wp_insert_term( 'test', 'post_tag', array('description' => 'This is a test tag') );
var_dump($x);
```

Its working fine. But it gets published automatically. Is it possible to publish it after admin approval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that

1. I have understood your (very brief) question and
2. you're not actually talking about the `post_tag`-taxonomy

then you have [`wp_insert_term()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_insert_term/), which is the underlying API function.

#### Edit

As to the comment, there's the need of meta data for a term and administrator approval.

WordPress currently has **no** native way of adding meta data to a taxonomy taxon. There're ideas "around" it. *IMHO* they clutter your DB-options table in seconds without a reason. There're other ways around this, but this would be too much for a single answer, so I can only recommend to find another way of handling tag maintenance.

Comment: Thanks kaiser. Can you check my question update?. Your code working fine. But it gets published automatically. Is it possible to publish it after admin approval?

Comment: @Giri I'll post and update